# Rendering Folium maps in Flask

Tags: python, flask, folium

I’ve created a flask application that maps a couple of changing variables. Each time the browser window refreshes one element on the map should change.

Assume my folium map is `map`.

When I started I found the `map._repr_html_()` object. This worked perfectly for a couple of days and then stopped overnight.

I had made no changes to the code and now I just get a text representation of the html where the map should be.

Any ideas?

It looks like this; it’s quite lengthy. Sorry.

```
<div style="width:100%;"><div style="position:relative;width:100%;height:0;padding-bottom:60%;"><iframe src="about:blank" style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;left:0;top:0;border:none !important;" data-html=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 onload="this.contentDocument.open();this.contentDocument.write(atob(this.getAttribute('data-html')));this.contentDocument.close();" allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen></iframe></div></div>
```

The code used in ‘’’app.py’’’ is as follows:

To create the map:

```
map=folium.Map(zoom_level=0)
folium.Marker([userlat,userlon]).add_to(map)
folium.Marker([latitude,longitude],icon=folium.Icon(icon='cloud')).add_to(map)
```

To render the map to the .html:

```
return render_template('index.html',**pass_data, map=map._repr_html_())
```

To call the map in the html:

```
{{ map }}
```

Comment: Please, provide your code. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please fix the HTML if it's relevant or it's just rendered by folium?

Answer (score 3):

A solution was found, by adding the word ‘safe’ within the call for the Python object.

```
{{ map | safe }}
```